# Как заменить строку в выводе bash?

Tags: linux, bash

имеется вывод после команды grep:
"имя":"иван",
"имя":"петр",
"имя":"федор",
"имя":"жора",

какой командой можно заменить вывод для получения только имен?

иван
петр
федор
жора

Comment: Ещё раз грепнуть или использовать парсер json, так как похоже его и парсите

Comment: sed творит чудеса -- `avp@avp-desktop:~$ echo ' "имя":"иван", "имя":"петр", "имя":"федор", "имя":"жора",' | sed 's/"имя"://g' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/,//g'
 иван петр федор жора
avp@avp-desktop:~$ `

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo -n '"имя":"иван", "имя":"петр", "имя":"федор", "имя":"жора",' |tr ',' '\n' |awk -F'"' '{print $4}'
иван
петр
федор
жора
```

если нужен вывод именно в одну строку то:

```
$ echo -n '"имя":"иван", "имя":"петр", "имя":"федор", "имя":"жора",' |tr ',' '\n' |awk -F'"' '{print $4}' |tr '\n' ' '
иван петр федор жора
```